# EF Core context.SaveChanges() работает очень медленно после большого числа сохранений

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

В проекте требуется сделать ряд проверок при старте, и при необходимости пересчитать около 4 таблиц целиком.

Я заметил, что чем больше сохранений делает EF, тем медленнее он после этого работает. К примеру, если сперва пересчитать половину, а после перезагрузив программу, вторую половину, то все делается в пределах 20 минут. Однако если все считать без вмещательств, то процесс растягивается на 3 часа именно из-за сохранения в базу.

Перед пересчетом, одна из таблиц полностью удаляется. (довольно большая и тяжелая)

Подскажите, возможно данные где-то кешируются и можно ли отчищать этот кеш?

Comment: Это случаем не транзакция у вас размером в 3 часа? Покажите код.

Comment: @aepot код показать не могу, он разбит по нескольким частям и довольно объемен. Нет это не транзакция. Сперва происходат запросы на чтение и удаление строк где есть непересчитанные данные, затем цикл по таблице и пересчет ряда столбцов. После идет еще один цикл в котором полностью пересчитывается завершающая таблица. Как уже говорил, если пересчет делать по частям то в 20 минут примерно укладываюсь. Но если полностью все запустить, то тормозит сильно именно на сохранении в базу.

Comment: Объемный код - это сколько тысяч строк? Вы все-таки попытайтесь. Не надо публиковать весь код, достаточно только проблемную его часть.

Comment: Он разбит по частям в одном классе около 300 строк в другом приметно столько же, а третий вообще в перемешку логика и код базы с проверками. Да не оптимально, но проект разрастался в попыхах и я к нему недавно присоединился.  так что просто код не юудет информативен. проблема именно в поведении базы. К примеру есть база из 300000 строк суммарно, где часть данных созраняются в Json формате, пересчитать все нужно (синзронно) и под конец метод созранения будет сильно тормозить. т.е. не в коде дело а в EF. Код зоть и неоптимален, но работает очень быстро.

Comment: Попробуйте создать пустую базу, сгенерить туда похожие таблицы, написать свой код, который выполняет похожие действия с базой. Если поведение повторится, получится воспроизводимый пример - его здесь и опубликуйте. Если не повторится, то одно из двух - либо вы уже решили проблему, либо тест не получился.

Comment: не выйдет, много работы, мало временни. вопрос был про поведение EF, возможно кто сталкивался с подобным уже и есть опыт решения.

Comment: Сталкивался с чем? С торможением при продолжительном обращении к базе? Я думаю, все сталкивались, вот только причин может быть разных миллион, и еще одна. Последняя находится между клавиатурой и креслом. :) В вашем вопросе нет конкретики. Вряд-ли в тему, но [вот что нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15828811/12888024).

Comment: Вероятно, включен трекинг сущностей и на протяжении всех расчётов используется один и тот же контекст. Либо отключите трекинг, либо пересоздавайте контекст.

Comment: Кардинальный вариант: выкинуть EF, взять [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db). Другой вариант: использовать [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

Comment: Вариантов действительно может быть куча, начиная от не назначенных индексов в базе, заканчивая логикой кода. Возможно как вариант переопределить логику сохранения данных (собирать данные в одну кучу и затем делать обновление\запись).

Comment: Всё уже сказали в комментах выше. EF читает из базы данные и хранит (может не хранить если указывать AsNoTrackingChanges) данные для трекинга. Вопрос настолько неконкретный, что мы даже не знаем, можно ли не трекать данные и советовать отключить трекинг (а то можно только ухудшить ситуацию). Советы общего вида: переделывайте алгоритм, чтобы считать частично, порциями, уходите от EF совсем и т.п. Но если у вас огромная таблица, вы её всю читаете -- у вас проблемы с EF только часть проблем, могут всплыть и другие, можно обменять одни на другие.

Comment: В крупных приложениях даже рекомендуют делать несколько разных контекстов, указывая только часть таблиц, а не всю базу. Вполне возможно (зависит от вашего кода) поможет рекомендация все чтения обернуть в AsNoTracking.

Comment: Да, проблема была в контексте. решилась тем что на каждую длительную операцию был создан свой контекст. Всем спасибо.